# Application Screen distorted after iOS upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios4

The application which runs smoothly on 4.0.1 when was tried on run on 4.2.1 produced distorted screen i.e., screen somewhat moved to left by 20%.  Phones on which iOS 4.0.1 and 4.2.1 are installed are 2 different phones.  What could be the problem?

We observed that wherever we have added as subview this problem is occurring.

Thanks,
Satish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I think it is either that you are not setting the correct `view.autoresizingMask` properly or there is a subtle change in how views are being laid out.

Try setting the frame of the view that moved explicitly and see what happens.

```
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)]
```

Some related piece of code and/or screenshots would definitely help. Also, is it a UIKit application or a Cocos2D game?

---

**EDIT:** Since you can't provide code (or a stripped-down example version) I'll just post some code that I've been using.

Usually when I add subviews to "fill" a parent view, I had do the following:

```
UIView *parent = nil; // find parent view
UIView *child = nil; // child view to add to parent

[parent addSubview:child];

CGRect frame = [parent frame];
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[child setFrame:frame];
```

If you have done that and it still does not work I believe the problem might lies somewhere else (i.e. have you overridden `layoutSubviews` by any chance? or was the phone jailbroken?)

I highly doubt it'll be a UIKit bug though but it is totally possible.

Comment: It is UIKit application.  We observed that all screens where we are adding as subview this problem exists.

Comment: we have set autoresizingMask and also used setFrame as suggested.  Problem still persists.

Comment: @user1072977 can you post some relevant code? Easier when I see the code.

Comment: @user1072977 also, by "subview" how are you adding the subview? I have observed cases where the frame is re-set to a wrong size on adding.

Comment: @user1072977 especially when rolling your own custom tabbar/navbar controllers.

Comment: I cannot.  It is confidential.  But there is nothing tricky we are doing.  just wherever we are adding another view as subview to the current view then this problem exists.  When we push to navigation controller such views are not coming as distorted.

Comment: we are setting the frame size correctly while adding as subview.  Or else it would have been distorted in 4.0.1 phone as well.

Comment: @user1072977 unless you provide some more info, I can't really help you further than that.

Comment: Thanks @chakrit.  We set the frame of child view to Parent's view as per your example.  It solved the problem.

Comment: @user1072977 ah, cool :). Seems, the thing was because `addSubview` changes the frame of child view so you have to do it _after_ adding the subview. I guess this behavior starts after 4.0.1 (it's there in 5+ OSes).

Comment: @user1072977 then if you would please mark my answer as accepted (clicking on the checkmark) I'd be really appreciated. :)